# UIPickerView won't show

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have been trying for 2 days now to get a UIPickerView to show and I am at a loss.  I have implemented all the methods to connect a data source (NSArray) and have no idea why I can't get it to show.  The assignment is now due tonight and the professor is less than useless, I've given up asking her.

This is the .m file of the subview containing the UIPickerView.  All I need is to figure out why the picker won't display!  Help appreciated I'm exasperated....

```
#import "SpotPicker.h"

@implementation SpotPicker
@synthesize spotPicker;

NSArray *pickerLocations;
NSString *selectedLocation;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
self.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

pickerLocations = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Grand Canyon", @"Mt Rushmore", @"Statue of Liberty", @"Empire State Building", @"Hollywood Sign", @"Lincoln Memorial", @"Space Needle", nil];
}
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[self setSpotPicker:nil];
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (IBAction)dismissPicker:(id)sender {
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView {
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
return [pickerLocations count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
return [pickerLocations objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
//NSLog(@"Selected Color: %@. Index of selected color: %i", [pickerLocations objectAtIndex:row], row);
selectedLocation = [pickerLocations objectAtIndex:row];
}

-(NSString *) getLocation {
return selectedLocation;
}

@end
```

Here's the header file to just to make sure I haven't declared something incorrectly or something stupid

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SpotPicker : UIViewController

- (IBAction)dismissPicker:(id)sender;
-(NSString *) getLocation;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *spotPicker;

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare that your `SpotPicker` implements the `UIPickerViewDelegate` and `UIPickerViewDataSource` protocols:

```
@interface SpotPicker : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>
```

and set your `UIPickerView`'s delegate to be your `SpotPicker`. You could either do this in IB, or programatically:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...
    self.spotPicker.delegate = self;
    self.spotPicker.dataSource = self;
}
```

Comment: Eureka!  Thank you so much :-D that was all I needed thank you thank you!